# Do the left and right "parts" of the matrix used when performing Gaussian Elimination have names?

Tags: matrices, terminology, gaussian-elimination

Given a matrix used to perform Gaussian Elimination like this:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 & | & 1 \\
2 & -7 & | & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which would be derived from a system of equations like this:

$$
\begin{cases}
x - 3y = 1 \\
2x - 7y = 3
\end{cases} 
$$

Do the different "sides", i.e. the parts that come from the right hand side of the equation and the part that comes from the left hand side of the equation, respectively, have names?

Comment: This comment doesn't answer your question, but it's called an augmented matrix

Comment: The left side is the coefficient matrix, and the right side is the column vector of constant terms

Comment: @J.W.Tanner that sounds like an answer, thanks! How come you post it as a comment?

Comment: Sorry; I'll post it as an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left side is the [coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_matrix) matrix, and the right side is the column vector of constant terms.

Together, they comprise an [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix).